# Canopy Does not Start on Windows 7 despite successful installation

Tags: enthought, epd-python

I have a 64bit Windows 7 machine. Never had issues with EPD.
I repeatedly tried to install both 64bit and /or 32bit Enthought Canopy.
Despite installation being successful neither of them starts.
I looked on Task Manager and the process does not even start.
I have removed every other version of Python I have had and still no ability to launch caonpy

any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please share your log files located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\log`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the environmental variables called PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME 
Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced Settings > Environmental variables.

Also see: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-