# During Enthought Canopy install, canopy.exe fails to run to setup environment on Windows 7

Tags: enthought, canopy

I have a 64bit Win 7, installed the 64 bit canopy.

The first part installs fine, but if I try to launch canopy to set up the environment from the start menu (or from the desktop icon or "*C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\Canopy.exe*" which is where they point) absolutely nothing happens.

This seems to be the same problem that has been reported a few times before:

[Canopy Does not Start on Windows 7 despite successful installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816468/canopy-does-not-start-on-windows-7-despite-successful-installation)

[Install 32 bit Canopy on Win 7, 32-bit machine fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337137/install-32-bit-canopy-on-win-7-32-bit-machine-fails)

[Enthought canopy not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810558/enthought-canopy-not-running)

but none of these questions have been resolved. What they all have in common is that they relate to Windows 7.
These questions are followed up by a request for the log:
*"C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\log\"*

However there are no logs, there isn't even a 
*C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Enthought* directory.

However I have found that if I go into:

C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64

and run the copy of Canopy.exe in there it allows me to setup the environment and run canopy from within this subdirectory (the desktop and start menu links still fail) . This also creates the
*C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Enthought* directory and logs.

BUT I am worried if I do this I will cause problems for myself further down the line. Can someone tell me why the canopy.exe linked to in my start menu isn't working?

I do have a previous installation of WinPython 2.7 in
*C:\Python27\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3*

thanks

Susie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing PYTHONHOME and/or PYTHONPATH environment variables may be interfering with Canopy startup. For details, please see:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22508619-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything

Comment: I do have a pythonpath variable set for Autodesks Maya, PYTHONPATH = C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2011\Python\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2011\Python\Lib\site-packages\pymel and removing this solves the problem. This isn't the most ideal solution as Maya uses the Pythonpath variable for pymel, but I have found a way of setting it on launch of Maya instead so everything works now- thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. In a future version of Canopy we will be overriding PYTHONPATH in some contexts, but for your reference it really is not appropriate to make such settings system-wide when you have multiple Python installations (as you do -- Canopy and Autodesk, at least).

Comment: Since your question was answered, please mark it as such so that its status is clear. You are the only person who can mark it as answered. FYI doing this is standard stackoverflow protocol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report and pointers, Susie. No, you have not created any problem for yourself.

To help us get to the bottom of this, could you be so kind as to answer these questions?:

1) What is the full Target of the non-working shortcut? (Right Click / Properties / Shortcut tab / Target)

2) Can you start Canopy by running this?:

```
C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\Canopy.exe
```

3) In the light of your previous Python installation, what go you see if you type “PATH” at a command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

*1) What is the full Target of the non-working shortcut? (Right Click / Properties / Shortcut tab / Target)*

The non-working shortcut target is the filepath you give below:
C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\Canopy.exe

*2) Can you start Canopy by running this?:
C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\Canopy.exe*

No. I get about a half second of the spinning 'working' icon on my mouse pointer then stops.
If I run it from the command line it skips straight back out to the next line.

*3) In the light of your previous Python installation, what go you see if you type “PATH” at a command prompt?*

(formatted)

```
PATH=
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;
C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.7-Q16;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\windows\system32;
C:\windows;
C:\windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;
C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;
C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin;
D:\College\CVsoft\bundler\bin;
D:\College\CVsoft\bundler\pmvs2_64;
D:\College\CVsoft\Win64-VS2010;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;
C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin;
C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
D:\College\CVsoft\APERO\micmac;
C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
C:\Program Files\OpenNI\Bin64;
C:\users\susie\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;
C:\Users\susie\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User;
C:\Users\susie\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts
```

Comment: Thanks! I am hopeful that my 2nd answer will resolve your problem. Please confirm/deny.